# Can a .framework directory be stored as a file?

Tags: xcode, frameworks

I have a need to store an Xcode project with an included .framework directory in various places that don't support symbolic links (SVN* and a FAT32 USB stick). This breaks the framework, because it depends on those symbolic links.

Can a framework instead be stored as a single file, or a directory that doesn't require symlinks?

<sub>*:  SVN itself does support links, but not on Windows.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

The framework shouldn't require the symlinks. You should be able to "unwind" the symlinks by duplicating the directories. This wastes some space, but should work. An easy way to do this is with `rsync -L`:

```
rsync -aLv /source/path/Something.framework /dest/path
```

Side note: If possible, I recommend replacing the framework with a static library and headers (or just compile the underlying source code into your project, which is how I almost always do it). In my experience, frameworks often create more problems then they solve. Their primary benefit is when the same framework file can be shared between running processes (such as the frameworks in `/System`). A framework stored in your own bundle isn't "shared" and so doesn't gain the biggest benefits of frameworks. (If this is a closed-source package, then that's a different issue, and frameworks are very nice, but this is less common.)

Comment: Duplicating the dirs...that's so simple I wonder why I didn't come up with that myself :) Regarding the rest, as far as iOS/Objective-C development is concerned, I'm a copy-paste hero and try to avoid actual programming :p But thanks, I might still do that in the future.